# How to calculate the length of the negative parts of $ \cos \alpha x-\cos 2 \alpha x $?

Tags: trigonometry, periodic-functions, arc-length

I have this periodic function
$$  f(x) = \cos (\alpha  x)-\cos (2 \alpha  x)     $$
defined for $x>0$ and for $\alpha>0$.

> How can I find the length of the graph of $f$ along one of its period when $f(x) < 0$?

Here I have plotted the function:

$\hspace{3.5cm}$
[image]

Comment: Use formula $\int_{x_0}^{x_1} \sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}dx$ where $(x_0,x_1)$ is an interval on which $f(x)<0$

Comment: @JeanMarie that's exactly what I was going to suggest but then I saw the algebra-precalculus tag. Maybe mistagged?

Comment: If the OP hasn't been introduced to calculus, it's impossible to consider computing curve lengths...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Too long for a comment:*

The function is periodic in $x$ with period $T = -\frac{2\pi}{a}$.

Find the $x$ for which $f(x) < 0$ that are for example $x_1:=\frac{2\pi}{3a} \le x \le \frac{4\pi}{3a}=:x_2$. Then using the usual formula for evaluating the lenght of a curve you get:

$$L = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} \sqrt{1+f'(x) ^ 2}dx = \dots$$

[I used Wolfram for the calculations in an hurry]

Comment: Thanks, and then, I should sum all the lengths? is that right?

Comment: I dont agree with your interval $(x_1,x_2)$...

Comment: No, $L$ is the lenght of $f$ along one of its period. If you sum all the lenghts then you get $\infty$..

Comment: Your $x_1$ is erroneous ; you must take $x_1=\dfrac{2\pi}{3 \alpha}$; $x_2$ is correct.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you for pointing it out. I did quick calculations

Comment: @Gabrielek Many thanks, but I have two other questions. Excuse me if they are very elementary.  I obtain the length of negative and positive parts of this function for $a=1$ on its periodic domain as $\approx 4.64117$ and $\approx 6.42518$, respectively. Hence, the total length on the period is $\approx 11.0664$. Then, this sum should not be equal to the period which is $2\pi$? The second question: is the ratio of the negative length to the total length remains constant for any values of $a$?

Comment: The period is a distance on the $x$-axis, and we are evaluating the lenght of the graph of a function, so there is no link bewteen $2\pi$ and $L$.

Comment: I obtain the same values as you for$a=1$. I agree with @Gabrielek for the first result. Fot the second question: no, there is no reason that the ratio of lengthes keep the same value when $\alpha$ varies...